# Wordpress - Tubepress Javascript Error

Tags: wordpress, tubepress

Wondering if somebody might be able to help me out with this issue.  I'm using wordpress with the tubepress plugin.  For some reason, when you click on the videos to view it, nothing happens.  You can scroll over the videos and it appears to be a link but it won't do anything when you click on the thumbnail or the text.

Any thoughts?

http://www.cruxn.com/videos/

Thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the PHP error_log?

Also see your browser console to see if there are any JavaScript errors.